# Can't generate a file to download using js or php

Tags: javascript, php, file, icalendar

I know there are a lot of tutorials, but for some reason I am not managing to focus the search to my specific issue.

I want to have a link to download `<a href="#" download="cal.ics">click</a>`

For some reason it fills the file with all the echo's from my page instead of a string that i can prepare.

What am I missing?

**Edit**:

I want the file to contain the return of this function:

```
function createICS(){
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar; charset=utf-8'");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=calendar.ics");
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    PRODID:-//Geektike/eventsboard//IL
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    UID:123456789
    SUMMARY:asd
    DTSTART:20140520T210000Z
    DTEND:20140520T220000Z
    LAST-MODIFIED:20111115T103014Z
    LOCATION:here
    DESCRIPTION:cool
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR";

return $ical;
exit;
}
```

Comment: What is generating the ics?

Comment: for now nothing, I was expecting an empty file. later I'll use a string which I prepared using php.

Comment: Those echos from your page do not contain any useful exception information?

Comment: The page itself is dynamically built from `echo <html tag> ...`
all of these echoes are getting written to the file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `<a href="#" download="cal.ics">click</a>` will need to be this: `<a href="#" download="cal.php">click</a>`.

Then create the cal.php file and have this code inside it:

```
<?php
  print createICS();
?>
```

(That's as long as the cal.php file has access to the createICS() function, otherwise put that function in to the cal.php file as well).

Comment: I think you mean `print(createICS());`

Comment: Thank you, I followed your instructions, now it downloads the whole page, not only the echoes and download a php file rather than ics file.

Comment: still no luck, it keeps printing the whole page

Comment: @Meschiany, could you please clarify? or show us what you mean by 'printing the whole page'?

Comment: Of course, thank you for your patience.
cal.php file is : <html> <head> ..... [scripts][stylsheet] content content.... </head> </html>. Literally the whole page :)

Comment: I think what's going on here is that cal.php has items that are printing to the page before the header() function within the createICS() function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54049/discussion-between-thepav-and-meschiany).

Answer (score 0):

You must use output buffering to omit the data you don't want in the file.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: Thank you, I don't quite understand how it is related?
I think I am looking for something much easier, file with my php string.

Comment: My answer was based on the assumption that you have that function in an existing environment e.g. a framework. I think thePav's answer suits you better.